# python 'for' loop logic

Tags: python, loops, logic

New to python - don't understand why the following seems to skip x=2 ?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

for x in a:
    print("x=", x)
    print("a=", a)
    a.remove(x)
    print("new a=", a)
```

returns:

```
x= 1
a= [1, 2, 3]
new a= [2, 3]
x= 3
a= [2, 3]
new a= [2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: In general: if you mutate a sequence while iterating over it, the effects are usually somewhat undefined and/or unexpected.

Comment: It's because the loop walks through the indices not the values and I see that is a bug in conception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the list as you iterate over it.

On its first loop, it's looking at the first element of `a`. Then you remove the first element, changing `a` to `[2,3]`. On its second loop, its looking at the second element of `a`. Because `a` has changed, its second element is now 3, which is what you get.

Comment: Yes but it is unexpected behavior since the loop is not index-based, I think it   as a bug.

Comment: You can think whatever you like.

Comment: @Idle001 Python for loop (not foreach) is based on C for loop and therefore index-based. When iterated, list object yields indexes, as seen in xrange.

Comment: @VladislavToncharov I didn't know there is a `foreach` item iterator in python sorry both of you

Comment: @Idle001 There's no for loop in Python. There's foreach loop which is called for in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is iterating over the memory location of the list a. After you delete the first element in the list. The second element is stored in the memory location of the first. Thus the loop loops over the second memory location next which currently is storing the third element.